# MongoDB GridFS - Is it filename or fileName

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

Please look at the following image, from http://mongoexplorer.com/:

[image: http://mongoexplorer.com/]

I've been trying to work through GridFS, referencing https://github.com/jamescarr/nodejs-mongodb-streaming. The files I uploaded, come back nicely and the stream that comes back via the following get function looks right.

```
var gridfs = (function () {
    function gridfs() { }
    gridfs.get = function (id, fn) {
        var db, store;
        db = mongoose.connection.db;
        id = new ObjectID(id);
        store = new GridStore(db, id, "r", {
            root: "fs"
        });
        return store.open(function (err, store) {
            if (err) {
                return fn(err);
            }
            return fn(null, store);
        });
    };
    return gridfs;
})();
```

Using http://mongoexplorer.com/ I uploaded files into GridFS to test with, but they seem broken when I use the node code above to retrieve them.

That is when I noticed the filename / fileName thing. Looking here **/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js** I saw the reference to filename with a lowercase 'N', but in my GridFS, it's fileName with a capital 'N'.

OK, so just for kicks, I changed it to lowercase in GridFS, but I still get some corruption in the stream (node code above) when retrieving files uploaded with http://mongoexplorer.com/.
Clicking **Save as...** in http://mongoexplorer.com/, however brings back my fine just perfectly.

To get back to my question, (since my tests didn't seem to prove anything,) I am wondering which is it:  filename with a lowercase 'N', or fileName with 'N' in caps?

Comment: ps. I don't have the 1500xp required to add [MongoExplorer] tag.

Comment: for the sake of my curiosity, I tried the same in c#... looks like there's something funny in the node.js GridFS driver. pity

Comment: Thought I'd just share some examples of what the code above does with a windows file. File uploaded with [MongoExplorer]. Also downloads fine with [MongoExplorer]. Node GridStore stream however mangles it. Here they are: [windows-before.txt](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1334455/windows-before.txt) and [windows-after.txt](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1334455/windows-after.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latest mongodb native driver as there are a ton of fixes for GridFS, there is a ton of examples in the github directory for the driver under the tests for usage of GridFS as streams as well.

Docs are at

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native

In general I would say that if you use the core functionalities stick to the driver as the one you are using it using a driver that' way of of date which explains you corruption issues.

Comment: I was using version 0.9.9-8. I understand your reasoning about using the latest node driver, but have to say I am concerned that we're on a bit of a node island... 

MongoDB isn't just for node.js. What about supporting files uploaded to GridFS using other platforms. Is the answer really that you have use node to write the files you want to read with node? Giving in to that way of thinking really makes the technology fleeting.

Comment: To prove my point, look at how much node has changed in the short few months. I would like to see node just settle a bit so one can finish a project without having to rewrite every few weeks.  

Please tell me if you have ever tried to open a file from GridFS, which you did not upload yourself with node.js or your own driver? Please don't take offence, but one has to be mindful of the world beyond node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Another Windows tool nl. MongoVue also looks for *filename* instead of *fileName*. I'd say the answer is more likely filename instead of fileName.

---

With retrieving the small Windows file from GridStore, I found a bug, but I don't know how to fix it. I guess there must be some value like Chunk.CurrentSize or the like, but looking at the chunk.js file in the native node mongo driver https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/gridfs/chunk.js, I did the following...

I found this:

```
Chunk.prototype.readSlice = function(length) {
  if ((this.length() - this.internalPosition + 1) >= length) {
    var data = null;
    if (this.data.buffer != null) { //Pure BSON
      data = this.data.buffer.slice(this.internalPosition, this.internalPosition + length);
    } else { //Native BSON
      data = new Buffer(length);
      length = this.data.readInto(data, this.internalPosition);
    }
    this.internalPosition = this.internalPosition + length;
    return data;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

and moved the following

```
data = this.data.buffer.slice(this.internalPosition, this.internalPosition + length);
```

into the this if statement  (1024 * 256 is the value from Chunk.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 256;)

```
    if (this.data.buffer != null) { //Pure BSON
      if (this.data.buffer.length > 1024 * 256) {
        // move to here
      } 
      else 
      {
        data = this.data.buffer;
      }
```

like so:

```
Chunk.prototype.readSlice = function(length) {
  if ((this.length() - this.internalPosition + 1) >= length) {
    var data = null;
    if (this.data.buffer != null) { //Pure BSON
      if (this.data.buffer.length > 1024 * 256) {
        data = this.data.buffer.slice(this.internalPosition, this.internalPosition + length);
      } 
      else 
      {
        data = this.data.buffer;
      }
    } else { //Native BSON
      data = new Buffer(length);
      length = this.data.readInto(data, this.internalPosition);
    }
    this.internalPosition = this.internalPosition + length;
    return data;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

The issue with windows files smaller than the chunk size is solved, but this isn't the most elegant solution. I'd like to propose this as the answer, but I realize using the default chunk size hard coded isn't the dynamic value which would make this less of a workaround ;-)

Comment: Looks like the problem is the GridFS Readstream support for small ASCII files then?